# evalJSON is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

following is my code.

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    var dataName = new Array();
    $.get('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/empBox/ajaxToGetCodes.do', function (responseText) {
        var JSONcustomers = $.evalJSON(responseText);
        var total = JSONcustomers["arrayObj1"].length;
        var index = 0;
    });
```

Although i'm getting the response text. But its not able to convert it to json.
Giving the following error.

`$.evalJSON is not a function.`

Am adding all the necessary library to it.
jquery-json.js
and jquery.js

Any idea, what may be the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all!!

Actually due to some other internal script problem, the jquery-json plugin file although showing loaded in the DOM but was not recognizable by the calling method.

So i used $.getScript, now my code looks like the following

```
$.get('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/empBox/ajaxToGetCodes.do', function (responseText) {
$.getScript("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/web/include/js/jquery.json-2.2.min.js",
    var JSONcustomers = $.evalJSON(responseText);
    var total = JSONcustomers["arrayObj1"].length;
    var index = 0;
});
});
```

And, this solved my problem!! :)

Answer (score 3):

It's `$.parseJSON`

...more text to satisify 30 char limit

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually parsing the JSON, why not simply use getJSON that does this for you?

Read the documentation at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's `$.parseJSON`

If you want to use evalJSON, here's the plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

Comment: You try this first `$.get('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/empBox/ajaxToGetCodes.do', function (responseText) {
        alert(responseText);
    });` to check whether the returned data is in valid format or not, or whether it is returned or not. ^^